# How to write a method that return the sum of a given column in a array? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I should create a method that print the sum of a given column in the main. This program shows a compilation error of:

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at algproo2.ALGPROO2.sumColumn(ALGPROO2.java:29)
at algproo2.ALGPROO2.main(ALGPROO2.java:24)
```

Java Result: 1

What should i do?

```
public class ALGPROO2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] a = {
            {-5,-2,-3,7},
            {1,-5,-2,2},
            {1,-2,3,-4}
        };
        System.out.println(sumColumn(a,1)); //should print -9
        System.out.println(sumColumn(a,3)); //should print 5
    }
    public static int sumColumn(int[][] array, int column)
    {
      int sumn = 0;
      int coluna [] = array[column];
      for (int value : coluna )
      {
        sumn += value;
      }
      return sumn; 
    }


}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero index based. The last index of `a` is `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `int coluna [] = array[column];` you're actually getting one row, not the column. For example:

Doing `array[1]` would give you this array:

```
{1,-5,-2,2}
```

Thus, doing `array[3]` will give you an error as there is no 4th row / 4th array (as arrays start at 0). Instead, you need to loop over your rows (ie the number of rows is `array.length`). Then at each row, you can access the value at that particular column:

```
public static int sumColumn(int[][] array, int column) {
  int sumn = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int row[] = array[i]; // get the row
    int numFromCol = row[column]; // get the value at the column from the given row
    sumn += numFromCol; // add the value to the total sum

  } 
  return sumn; // return the sum
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth response Nick! That will work for me! :)